# Cassandra nodetool repair deletes all columns on all replicated node after one node failure

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have set replication factor to 2 for two nodes connected in a cluster. I use node1 as contact point to cluster. I start my application which writes rows to DB and after writing few rows I stop Cassandra on the node2 which causes rows to be written to node1 (and no rows get written to node2 althuogh it was up during a few row writes still DB is empty after node is restarted, but why?). Anyway, I try to sych DBs by running nodetool repair but both nodes DBs show as empty after runnung the command. How can I get nodes synched?

Answer (score 0):

I had to set consistency level to ANY for writes to be taken care of using Cassandra's "Hinted Hand-off"